# Is the vertical velocity of a orbital spacecraft at apogee is zero relative to earth's surface?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, velocity, rocket-science

When I throw a ball up, it goes up and then at its highest point, its instantaneous vertical velocity is zero relative to me. is this same for an orbital spacecraft at it highest point in orbit (apogee) excluding the sideways velocity of that spacecraft?

Comment: The thrown ball is an orbital spacecraft;  one with a sub-surface perigee...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the vertical component of velocity in an elliptical orbit is zero at apogee. The object in orbit was going up before reaching that point and coming down after.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying!